# How to use .settings files in .NET core?

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-core

I'm porting an application to .NET core which relies on a `.settings` file. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to read it from .NET core. Normally, adding the following lines to the `.csproj` would generate a `TestSettings` class that would let me read the settings.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="TestSettings.settings">
        <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Unfortunately, this no longer seems to do anything. I can't even verify that the `SettingsSingleFileGenerator` runs at all. This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2782) suggests that this is a bug with the new `.csproj` format, but no one has offered an alternative.

What is the proper way of reading `.settings` files in .NET core?

Comment: Even if the Visual Studio-specific issues with `SettingsSingleFileGenerator` were resolved, I don't think the "Settings" system would work with .NET Core anyway because of their dependencies on `System.Configuration`. (I haven't verified this is the case)

Comment: Could you write a quick XML parser to read `.settings` files and the runtime `app.config` file to extract the values? That might be quicker and easier than trying to get the "Settings" feature in VS to work.

Comment: @Dai - I'm definitely able to write an XML parser, or use an off-the-shelf one, to do this, but since it's a standard format, I'd like to use a supported library to read it. I don't really want to get into the business of maintaining a settings file parser for Microsoft.

Comment: Also, as of .NET Core 2.0 (which I'm using) `System.Configuration` is available.

Answer (score 8):

For .NET Core 2.x, use the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` namespace (see note below), and there are tons of extensions on NuGet you'll want to grab for reading from sources ranging from environment variables to Azure Key Vault (but more realistically, JSON files, XML, etc).

Here's an example from a console program that retrieves settings the same way we use them when Kestrel starts up for our Azure sites:

```
public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; } = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)

    // This allows us to set a system environment variable to Development
    // when running a compiled Release build on a local workstation, so we don't
    // have to alter our real production appsettings file for compiled-local-test.
    //.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)

    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    //.AddAzureKeyVault()
    .Build();
```

Then in your code that needs settings, you just reference `Configuration` or you register `IConfiguration` for dependency injection or whatever.

Note: `IConfiguration` is read-only and will likely never get persistence per [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/issues/386#issuecomment-445504262) comment. So if reading AND writing are required, you'll need a different option. Probably `System.Configuration` *sans* designer.

Comment: What's the difference between `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` and `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` in .NET Core 2.0?

Comment: It's a complete rewrite / redesign. The `System` version was a monolithc, static, XML-focused feature. The new one is extensible and DI-friendly (which also makes it easier to unit test, if you're into that).

Comment: I should also note that if you're using ASP.NET Core (not just .NET Core, or a .NET Standard class library), there is a different concept you should [read about](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?tabs=basicconfiguration). Oh and the new system supports configuration-binding, which is deserializing a config section to a class with matching properties, very handy.

Comment: I actually think than using Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() being a potential cause of bugs ( typically is a newbie error )

Comment: This answer is only half-correct. If you came here looking for a store to read from and persist data to, Don't go down the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration road, it's currently immutable (https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/issues/385). It seems like System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager or a custom Json.Net impl is the way to go. Ugh.

Comment: @Ani This isn't "half-correct" in any sense. Persistent data storage and configuration are two entirely separate concepts. If you landed here looking for persistent storage, you're on completely the wrong track. And it isn't "currently" immutable, if you actually read the backlogged item (also closed) it won't ever support persistence: [comment](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/issues/386#issuecomment-445504262)

Comment: Q: I'm porting an application to .NET core which relies on a .settings file.
A: For .NET Core 2.x, use the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration namespace

To me, that answer works only for READING values out of said file. Any nuances you may assume that "configuration" vs Settings is doesn't change that your answer seems to conflate the two by not explaining the differences. Also, the first line of your answer (quoted above) is clear in trying to steer OP to use `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` when it clearly wouldn't work like a Settings File does at all.

Comment: That the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration team decided to KEEP this readonly does not make this answer more relevant, only less.

Comment: @Ani The OP never mentions writing to the file. You're literally making up a use-case that is completely unrelated to the question.

Comment: I think the note makes your answer crystal clear as opposed to the fact that it simply left out persistence entirely in its original form. Feel free to reject edits or rephrase your answer. Take it how you wish.

Comment: No, appsettings,json is not an alternative to Settings.settings. Appsettings.json is a .NET Core version of app.config which is a different scenario. Settings.settings is used to load and store user's options on running application. It is not application configuration file intended to avoid hardcoded parameters in program.

Comment: @user3625699 Nobody is talking about that here (and for what it's worth, I guess, I've never seen or heard of "settings.settings" as a standard filename for any app).

Comment: @McGuireV10 that is because you have never done desktop apps which was a big part of C# and today it become more minor but still exists

Comment: @user3625699 I was doing "desktop apps" before the Internet existed. I professionally write and maintain wildly complex trading apps for the financial industry. You don't know what you're talking about. That aside, it's irrelevant to the original question and my response.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way this is "proper", as I asked in the question, but I'm using this as a stop-gap until something more reasonable comes along. I cannot guarantee it will work for anyone else.

Include your `.settings` file as an embedded resource, then use it like this:

```
private static readonly ConfigurationShim Configuration = new ConfigurationShim("MyApp.Settings.settings");
public static bool MyBoolSetting => (bool) Configuration["MyBoolSetting"];
```

Code:

```
internal class ConfigurationShim
{
    private static readonly XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01/settings";

    private readonly Lazy<IDictionary<string, object>> configuration;

    public ConfigurationShim(string settingsResourceName)
    {
        configuration = new Lazy<IDictionary<string, object>>(
            () =>
            {
                Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(settingsResourceName))
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    XDocument document = XDocument.Load(reader);
                    return document.Element(ns + "SettingsFile")
                                   .Element(ns + "Settings")
                                   .Elements(ns + "Setting")
                                   .Select(ParseSetting)
                                   .ToDictionary(kv => kv.Item1, kv => kv.Item2);
                }
            });
    }

    public object this[string property] => configuration.Value[property];

    private static (string, object) ParseSetting(XElement setting)
    {
        string name = setting.Attribute("Name").Value;
        string typeName = setting.Attribute("Type").Value;
        string value = setting.Element(ns + "Value").Value;

        Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);
        IEnumerable<ConstructorInfo> ctors = GetSuitableConstructors(type);
        IEnumerable<MethodInfo> staticMethods = GetSuitableStaticMethods(type);

        object obj = null;
        foreach (MethodBase method in ctors.Cast<MethodBase>().Concat(staticMethods))
        {
            try
            {
                obj = method.Invoke(null, new object[] {value});
                break;
            }
            catch (TargetInvocationException)
            {
                // ignore and try next alternative
            }
        }

        return (name, obj);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<MethodInfo> GetSuitableStaticMethods(Type type)
    {
        // To use a static method to construct a type, it must provide a method that
        // returns a subtype of itself and that method must take a single string as
        // an argument. It cannot be generic.
        return type.GetMethods().Where(method =>
        {
            ParameterInfo[] parameters = method.GetParameters();
            return !method.ContainsGenericParameters &&
                   method.IsStatic &&
                   parameters.Length == 1 &&
                   parameters[0].ParameterType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string)) &&
                   type.IsAssignableFrom(method.ReturnType);
        });
    }

    private static IEnumerable<ConstructorInfo> GetSuitableConstructors(Type type)
    {
        // We need a constructor of a single string parameter with no generics.
        return type.GetConstructors().Where(ctor =>
        {
            ParameterInfo[] parameters = ctor.GetParameters();
            return !ctor.ContainsGenericParameters &&
                   parameters.Length == 1 &&
                   parameters[0].ParameterType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: _Please_, someone, find an alternative to this. I hesitated to post it here; someone might use it.

Comment: There would not be much reason to embed a settings file in your resources unless you only use it to write a default file when no settings file was found. The idea behind having a settings file in the first place is to enable users to configure stuff by editing it, which is not easy when it's embedded.

Answer (score 1):

When porting existing projects I usually copy the generated Settings.Designer.cs from the old to the new project. But I know, this is bad for changing the Settings-file or adding new Settings-Keys.
I also noticed that the user's settings were deleted after installing a new version, what was not the case with .net-Framework-Settings.

Comment: See that net Core-Apps can have several configuration Providers: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt632279.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt632279.aspx)