# Where is my Settings in project properties menu ? (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I created Console app project in Visual Studio. When I try to open the Settings menu in Project Properties, I can't see it. Also, I don't have properties in Solution Explorer. How can I create a Settings file in my project?

[image: Step1]

[image: Step2]

Comment: About settings in .NET Core project, maybe you can refer to [How to use .settings files in .NET core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48858172/how-to-use-settings-files-in-net-core).

Answer (score 0):

Open your project and right-click on your project folder. Go to:
Add => Add New File then
Search for Application Configuration file and add it to your project.

[Click here](https://blog.submain.com/app-config-basics-best-practices/) for a link that will help with what settings and configurations you can add to your App.Config file